# Button Click to set value in table input fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, odoo-10

I have table structure has created in 
https://jsfiddle.net/u8sdko1a/1/

in Button Click i want to set value in table input fields.

Js Code:

```
   $('#regform tr#cny-1131').each(function() {

       $(this).find("input.dedicate").val(name);
       $(this).find("input.chinese_name").val(chinese_name);

});
```

This code is working in Firefox but not in IE and Chrom.

Please anyone help to resolve this issue

Comment: What and from where the name and chinese_name vals you are setting here? And js fiddle is not setting  the value in firefox  too.

Comment: well, your fiddle doesn't work, but this is because jQuery is used but not included in the fiddle: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Comment: First of all check if Jquery selector gives any results at all:
    alert($(this).find("input.dedicate").length);

Also check syntax of "each". It takes 2 params: index and element. So change your code to the following:


    $('#regform tr#cny-1131').each(function(idx, element){
        $(element).find("input.dedicate").val(name);
        $(element).find("input.chinese_name").val(chinese_name);
    });

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of errors in your jsfiddle. First you have not included the JQuery to load on the page load. Then you have used the id selector `regform-0` and `regform` which is id for `<td>` and from that you have used `$('#regform-0 tr#cny-cny-1130')` which will look for a `<tr>` that is the child of element with id `#regform-0`. Since the element with id `regform-0` is itself a `<td>` how can it find a `<tr>` as a child. Another mistake was in the class name for `dedicated`, it's `dedicate`. Overall the working code is like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".cny_order").on("click", function(e) {
                $('#chinese tr.cny_item').find("input.dedicate").val("Tesst");
                $('#chinese tr.cny_item').find("input.chinese_name").val("erer");
});
});
```

For your workaround here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4u8ajjxs/1/)